# Applying l'Hopital's rule to show that the limit of a function is infinite whenever the limit of its derivative is

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Is the following statement is true ?

Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be a differentiable function such that $$\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=\infty\text{ or }{-\infty}\text,$$ then $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty\text{ or }{-\infty}$?

According to me it’s true as $$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}x=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}\cdot\lim_{x\to\infty}x$$ Now by applying L'HOSPITAL'S RULE (W. Rudin, Theorem $5.13$), we have $$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}x=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}\cdot\lim_{x\to\infty}x=\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)\cdot\lim_{x\to\infty}x=\pm\infty.$$ Please suggest. Thank you.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I edited question .

Comment: The limit of a product equals the product of the limits *if both of those limits exist*. You cannot break up the limit that way.

Comment: Yes, this is fine.  You might want to rephrase this so that first you prove that the limit of $ f ( x ) / x $ and the limit of $ x $ exist (as infinity) before baldly stating that the limit of $ f ( x ) $ is their product; but they do exist, so the limit of $ f ( x ) $ is their product, and that's $ \pm \infty $ (accordingly as the limit of $ f ' ( x ) $ is $ \pm \infty $.)  You might also look for a more elegant proof that avoids L'Hôpital's Rule (perhaps using the Mean-Value Theorem directly), but that's a matter of taste rather than correctness.

Comment: (Also, if you're going to cite a proof of L'Hôpital, make sure that it's not a proof of a weak version that requires the derivatives to be continuous, since you don't have that here.  But the theorem is true without that requirement, only with a more complicated proof, and I'd expect Rudin to prove it that way.)

Comment: @TobyBartels ok am trying according

Comment: @TobyBartels I would disagree that the limit "exists" if it equals infinity, or that it can be broken up in that case (though for the specific instance it might be argued directly). If you could, then as $x\to\infty$,let's break up the limit of $2x/x$ into the product of the limit of $2/x$ and $x$, both of which "exist."

Comment: Just an additional note, if $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)>0$, then too $f(x)\to +\infty$ as $x\to+\infty$ in case $f$ is differentiable. In any case, the rigourous way to go about this, is using Lagrange's Mean Value Theorem

Comment: @ArturoMagidin : In the terminology I know, the limit exists, but doesn't converge. But however you say it, it is a theorem that if $\lim f(x)=\pm\infty$ and $\lim g(x)=\infty$, then $\lim f(x)g(x)=\pm\infty$, and that's what this proof needs. (More generally, if $\lim f(x)$ and $\lim g(x)$ both exist in this extended sense, then $\lim f(x)g(x)$ exists *if* the product of the limits exists, where $\pm\infty\cdot\infty$ is defined to be $\pm\infty$ but $0\cdot\infty$ is undefined. I guess my comment was a little cavalier about that *if*.)

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron : That's a very good point. Incidentally, this can also be proved using L'Hôpital, since we have $a\infty=\infty$ whenever $a>0$ (in the extended real-number system, which applies when taking limits). Although I do think that your MVT proof is better, for using a more fundamental theorem. (And of course it also easily adapts to the more general case.)

Comment: Another warning about L'Hôpital: Besides requiring the derivative to be continuous, many textbooks also require the numerator to have an infinite limit (in the case where the denominator has an infinite limit). In this case, that would be begging the question! The theorem is true without any assumptions about the limit of the numerator (again, in the case where the denominator has an infinite limit), so your argument is still valid. Hopefully Rudin has this general version. (But that's another reason to prefer the MVT proof; the prerequisites will be familiar to more people.)

Comment: @TobyBartels Whereas in the terminology I use and know, the limit does not exist *because* it doesn't converge. I agree that if $f$ and $g$ each goes to $\infty$ or $-\infty$, then the limit of $fg$ goes to $\infty$ or $-\infty$ (depending on the interaction of the signs); which is why I said "it might be argued directly".

Comment: @ArturoMagidin : Ah, I thought that you meant that OP would need a detailed argument for these particular functions rather than relying on the general theorem about the limit of $fg$. If you meant to use that theorem, then aside from the usage of ‘exists’ (which to my mind is like asking whether $\sqrt{-1}$ exists: it depends on what kind of values you accept), then I agree.

Comment: @neelkanth : If you're still listening to this back-and-forth between me and Arturo, I think that the lesson here is that you should first prove (using L'Hopital) that the limit of $f(x)/x$ is $\pm\infty$, note that the limit of $x$ is $\infty$, and then explicitly cite a theorem about infinite limits to conclude that the limit of $f(x)/x\cdot x$ is $\pm\infty$. (Or do it all with the MVT as in Gandalf's answer, of course.)

Comment: @TobyBartels I personally don't think there's anything wrong with thinking of a limit tending to $+\infty$ as it "exists". I have always made a distinction between tending to $+\infty$ and not existing in the sense that $\lim\sup$ and $\lim\inf$ being different.  So I personally see no problem in the method Toby is suggesting and the op has used so far. On the other hand, I will say though that not all might be so "open" about this and I also would encourage to use analytical techniques on the "real line" (and not the "extended real line" whenever possible).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll only show the $+\infty$ direction as the other is similar.

As $f'(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$ , you have that $f'(x)>100$ for all $x\geq M_{0}$ for some $M_{0}>0$.

Now fix some $x>2M_0$

Now you have by Lagrange's Mean value theorem that for $\displaystyle\frac{f(x)-f(2M_{0})}{x-2M_{0}}=f'(c)$ for some $c\in [2M_{0},x]$

Hence $f(x)-f(2M_{0})=(x-2M_{0})f'(c)\geq 100(x-2M_{0})$ by our hypothesis. And as $x>2M_0$ was arbitrarily chosen, the above inequality holds for all such $x>2M_0$.

Hence $f(x)\geq 100(x-2M_{0})+f(2M_{0})$ for all $x\geq 2M_{0}$

And hence $f(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$ .

Note that the "100" is not important. Even if $100$ is replaced by an arbitrary fixed positive number $a$, then too, by the same argument, you will have that $f(x)\geq a(x-2M_{0})+f(2M_{0})$ for all "large enough" $x$ which would still give you that $f(x)\to \infty$. As I mentioned in the comments, one need meerly have $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)>0$ to conclude like this.

For the $-\infty$ case, use the same technique and notice that then $f'(x)<-100$ for all $x\geq M_{0}$ for some $M_{0}>0$